# Is it necessary to keep all the requests in saga or you can have separate modules for requests not related to redux and saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, saga

As I understand if we make a request by using redux-saga, the response is going to be stored into the redux store. But it is a bad practice to store all the stuff in the redux store. So is it ok to create separate module with API requests and use them when you do not want to put response in redux store ?
I would appreciate articles on this topic (couldn't find it on my own).

Answer (score 1):

Making requests in a file is totally fine in some cases. Just do it carefully in order to prevent interfering with app performance (if a component is rendered multiple time and you need just one request do it in the parent, etc.)

As for articles I couldn't find any to exactly this topic, but [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) have an example of api calls (please ignore the class one and check the hook example bellow). Now I would recommend you too use a service for this to abstract the fetch logic, but the idea is there and, while this cases shouldn't happen a lot, I don't see any reason to avoid this if you only need some data in a specific component and there is no use in saving it to the state .

EDIT:
You have [runSaga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/index.html#runsagaoptions-saga-args) which according to docs

> Allows starting sagas outside the Redux middleware environment. Useful if you want to connect a Saga to external input/output, other than store actions.

So you don't really need another library. Regarding the architectural problem this is what I was trying to emphasis with the react docs. I don't know if there are any articles in this direction (on a quick search I couldn't find any either), but I think for most of the data you want a reducer to prevent unnecessary reloading of the same data.
However there isn't anything suggesting not to do it as far as I know (neither in docs, articles, etc.). Moreover, in some cases, this can a good thing, and the fact that no docs suggest otherwise is a prove in this direction IMO.

PS: Also a discussion about using saga without redux [here](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1198)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I meant if it is ok to have in the project two places with API requests (saga and common requests by using axis for example). 
It is more an architectural question.

Comment: I did edit the question. I was somehow aware that the question was not about the possibility of do it, but I don't think there were any elaborated discussions about this. Not as far as I know at least.  So this is just an opinion. Not a rule or anything.